# /var/log/messages not sending to the rsyslog central logging server

Tags: centos7, syslog, rsyslog

Everything else is being logged to the central rsyslog server but not the /var/log/messages of the rsyslog client.

server: **learn** -> **192.168.1.100**

client: **server101** -> **192.168.1.200**

From the rsyslog server:

```
[root@learn ~]# ls -l /var/log/server101/
total 320
-rw------- 1 root root    775 Apr 28 09:46 clamd.log
-rw------- 1 root root   2596 Apr 28 09:45 CROND.log
-rw------- 1 root root 267683 Apr 28 09:48 kernel.log
-rw------- 1 root root    276 Apr 28 09:47 named.log
-rw------- 1 root root    209 Apr 28 09:37 opendkim.log
-rw------- 1 root root    426 Apr 28 09:42 phpMyAdmin.log
-rw------- 1 root root   2036 Apr 28 09:12 polkitd.log
-rw------- 1 root root   4758 Apr 28 09:37 postfix.log
-rw------- 1 root root   2174 Apr 28 09:13 rsyslogd.log
-rw------- 1 root root    699 Apr 28 09:37 sshd.log
-rw------- 1 root root   4645 Apr 28 09:45 systemd.log
-rw------- 1 root root    237 Apr 28 09:37 systemd-logind.log
```

From the rsyslog client, /var/log/messages file is being written with logs locally.

`*.* @192.168.1.100:514` is already added on /etc/rsyslog.conf of the client **server101** to forward all locally generated log messages to the remote rsyslog server **learn**

Not sure what is missing here.

Comment: Do you have a configuration anywhere on learn telling it to write to /var/log/messages?  The server sending the message can't tell the receiver what filename to use.  Syslog simply doesn't work like that.

Comment: @yoonix: yes indeed

`[root@learn ~]# grep "/var/log/messages" /etc/rsyslog.conf
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages`